# Query value is based off of what is entered into field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a page that will push an instagram photo out into a container based on a set value that it is querying on (i.e. looking for images with the # - sneakers) using the spectragram js library. However, what I want to do is allow the user to input/submit a hashtag value of their own (i.e. looking for images with the # - socks) through a form field, and return the latest instagram image based on that user query.

The problem is that I don't know how to properly modify the script to have whatever value the user enters to replace the value the script is looking for.

Here is the a sample of the script -

```
$('.test1').spectragram('getRecentTagged', { query: 'This is the value I want replaced with the user's value',size: 'big', max: 1, wrapEachWith: '<span></span>'});
```

There is probably a really simple solution to this. I'm sorry, I'm a newbie when it comes to  jquery and js.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $('textboxID').val(); //get value 

$('.test1').spectragram('getRecentTagged', { query: x,size: 'big', max: 1, wrapEachWith: '<span></span>'});
```

---

Typo Quotes mismatch

change `user's` to  `user\'s` escape single quote

```
$('.test1').spectragram('getRecentTagged', { query: 'This is the value I want replaced with the user\'s value',size: 'big', max: 1, wrapEachWith: '<span></span>'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tushar. Is the 'X' you placed in the query supposed to be the variable - 'textboxID' you created?